# Generating S3 bucket url for RestKit without using aws

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-s3, restkit

I have an app using RestKit successfully. I am building an IAP in the app and for iOS5 I needed a place to host the app files for the IAP. I decided using Amazon S3 for that.

Now I now that I can integrate amazon API but I wish to keep my app simple, and since I am using RestKit I just want to use it to download the files.

Is there a guide or explanation on how to generate a bucket url with expiration and secrets ?

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: all the information you need is in the [Authenticating REST Requests](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html) documentation page.

Also, it's not entirely clear from your question, but I hope you're putting the URL generation in some web app somewhere that you control, rather than directly embedding it in the IOS app. I also hope you're using IAM to restrict that key to the appropriate permissions level regardless.